# How to write a JavaScript function that takes a string and print out each letter of that string?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunc(str){
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        x = str.charAt(str[i]);
    }

    return x
}

console.log(myFunc("great"))
```

This only prints the first letter of the strings. Any help?

Comment: `[...str].forEach((char) => console.log(char));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

charAt accepts the character's *index* in the string as a parameter, not the character itself.

```js
function myFunc(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(str.charAt(i));
  }
}
myFunc('abc');
```

Another option is to avoid using charAt and simply use square brackets to identify the character:

```js
function myFunc(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(str[i]);
  }
}
myFunc('abc');
```

Comment: Answer is correct, but would be better if it included just a short description, something like: you can do `str.charAt(i)` or `str[i]`...but not both together

Answer (score 0):

Move the console.log into your loop.

```
function myFunc(str){
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        x = str.charAt(i);
        console.log(x);
    }
}

myFunc('great');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not enjoy ES6:

```js
[...`it's a string`].forEach(char => console.log(char));
```